# InvokeEvent: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: c#

```
private void manager_OnWebSiteVisited(object source, WebSiteVisitedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                txtStatus.BeginInvoke(new WebSiteVisitedCallback(WebSiteVisited), new object[] { args });
            else
                txtStatus.Invoke(new WebSiteVisitedCallback(WebSiteVisited), new object[] { args });
        }
```

InvokeEvent: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

i can use if (IsHandleCreated) but i do not know what to do if is not created. How to create it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just access the `Handle` property, it will create the handle if it's not already created. You can also call the `CreateHandle` method explicitly.

```
if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
{
    this.CreateHandle();
}
```

By the way, your usage of `InvokeRequired/Invoke/BeginInvoke` is wrong: if `InvokeRequired` is false, you shouldn't use `Invoke` at all, you should call the method directly. I think what you want to do is this:

```
        if (InvokeRequired)
            txtStatus.Invoke(new WebSiteVisitedCallback(WebSiteVisited), new object[] { args });
        else
            WebSiteVisited(args);
```

Comment: Just access the Handle property. How exactly did you mean that.

Comment: I mean get the value of the property. But anyway, it would probably be cleaner to create the handle explicitly. See the code in my updated answer